# how to edit article layout in JA Mero joomla template

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

i use JA Merro joomla template for my website.
but when i view the added article from user's site at that time some type os garbage values are displayed at start and end of the article.

**"горящие туры в Индонезию
история кинематографа"**

![error image][1]

i can check the com_content's tmpl/default.php file, but it doesn't work.
please help me to remove this....

Comment: You say you check the article "at that time". What time is that? are you saying that when you look at a different time the characters are no longer there?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `template/html/com_content/article/default.php` file in case there is a template override in place

Comment: This is likely the case, the path from the base of the install would be `templates/(template_name)/html/com_content/article/default.php`